# Setting perspective shadow in PowerPoing using C# VSTO

Tags: vsto, powerpoint

I am trying to set perspective shadows for text using VSTO C# and am unable to do so. I tried to set msoTristate property of the text as below:

shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs[j].Font.Shadow

This sets up only one kind of a shadow.

I also tried to set the ShadowFormat properties as shown below:

shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs[j].Font.Shadow.Blur //works fine

shape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Paragraphs[j].Font.Shadow.Type //throws an exception

I am able to get only one kind of shadow but am trying to get perspective shadows. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The perspective shadows are legacy shadows. They can be set up using enum values MsoShadowType.msoShadow39 thru MsoShadowType.msoShadow43. You can sent manipulate the other properties to tweak the perspective shadow.

`Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange[1].Shadow.Type = MsoShadowType.msoShadow39;`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried to use the above line of code. This is not throwing an exception as it was throwing earlier but still it is producing the same shadow and not a perspective one.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is to copy the shadow style from a shape and apply it to another shape. Now, in case of perspective text shadow the source shape type come out to be "msoShadowMixed" which is not supported.

Setting the shadow type as you stated sets the shadow as expected. But as I stated above that I want to copy shadow style from one shape to another. Is there a way I can get the shadow type of perspective shadows? As for all the cases: msoShadow39, msoShadow40, msoShadow41, msoShadow42, msoShadow43, the shadow type is showing to be msoShadowMixed.